# Word that means "to muse on thoughts"?

Tags: word-request, usage

I thought I could use *muse* like this:

> I must have been **musing** for too long because my
>   stomach began to groan.

But it doesn't seem to be the [right usage](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22%20been%20musing%20for%22&oq=%22%20been%20musing%20for%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i71k1l4.6654.6654.0.6731.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.TnAXJTSRDnw).

What's a better word? (To avoid writing "... been musing on these thoughts ...)

Comment: What's wrong with *thinking*? *Musing* is a little old-fashioned. *Ruminating* is possible, but some readers might not know what it means. If *thinking* is too prosaic for you, you could say "dwelling on these thoughts", but I'd go for *thinking*. It's simple, direct, and easily understood. Forget about five-dollar words.

Comment: @Mick I'm looking for a word that has "thinking" embedded in it.

Comment: You could possibly use *deep-thinking* or *over-thinking* (but, curmudgeon that I am, I wouldn't). [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*-thinking&ls=a) is a useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

To ***[brood](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brood)*** conveys the meaning you  looking for: 
​

> - to think for a long time about things that make you sad, worried, or angry:
>     *I wish she wouldn't sit brooding in her room all day.*

also 
***[Ruminate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ruminate):***

> - (formal) to think carefully and for a long period about something:
>     *She ruminated for weeks about whether to tell him or not.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'pondering', 'contemplating' or as suggested above, 'thinking'.